# Concerning kernels and closed subspaces of a reflexive separable Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If $X$ is a separable Banach space, then every closed subspace $C\subseteq X$ can be recovered as the kernel of some linear bounded operator $T:X\rightarrow X$. I was wondering if, and in case $X$ is reflexive (and separable), is there a countable family of linear bounded operators $T_n :X\rightarrow X$ such that one can identify every closed subspace $C$ of $X$ as $C=\ker(T_n -\lambda 1)$, for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Fix some $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$. Then, for eigenvalues $\lambda$, $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$, $\ker(T-\lambda 1)\cap\ker(T-\mu 1)\neq\lbrace 0\rbrace$ if and only if $\lambda =\mu$. So if one considers an uncountable chain of closed subspaces of $X$ and if each closed subspace is of the form $\ker(T-\lambda 1)$, for each element of the chain we would need a different linear operator. Such uncountable chains can easily be constructed in $\ell^{2}$ and thus I think the answer to the question should be negative.